# Trying to put in quotations around my printed result

Tags: python

```
file = open('english.txt','r') 
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for text in file:
    translated= []
    lines = text.split()
    print(' '.join(lines))
    print("Translated to pig latin becomes:")
    for words in lines:
        if words[0] in vowels:
            words = words + 'yay'
        else:
            while words[0] not in vowels:
                words = words[1:] + words[0]
            words = words + 'ay'
        translated.append(words)
    words = ' '.join(translated)
    print(words, '\n')
```

the results I am obtaining are:

```
this is a statement
Translated to pig latin becomes:
isthay isyay ayay atementstay 

its going through python
Translated to pig latin becomes:
itsyay oinggay oughthray onpythay 

and this is the result
Translated to pig latin becomes:
andyay isthay isyay ethay esultray 

the end
Translated to pig latin becomes:
ethay endyay
```

i want to have the 1st line and 3rd line in every one of the stanzas to have quotations are them.
for example "the end" "ethay endyay"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the quotes:

```
print('"' + words + '"\n')
```

Or use formatting:

```
print('"{}"\n'.format(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
print('"{}"\n'.format(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the object in the respective `print()` statements with quotation marks:

```
file = open('english.txt','r') 
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for text in file:
    translated= []
    lines = text.split()
    print('"'+' '.join(lines)+'"') # Here
    print("Translated to pig latin becomes:")
    for words in lines:
        if words[0] in vowels:
            words = words + 'yay'
        else:
            while words[0] not in vowels:
                words = words[1:] + words[0]
            words = words + 'ay'
        translated.append(words)
    words = ' '.join(translated)
    print('"'+words+'"', '\n') # And here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your quotes like this :

```
 print('"', words, '"', '\n')
```

Comment: This will put spaces around `words`.

Comment: wow yeah it was much easier than i was making it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def quoted(s):
    return '"%s"' % s

print(quoted(words), '\n')
```